# Pandas | add a root node when applying to_json

Tags: pandas, amazon-s3

I'm exportin a pandas datafarame to a json file using `orient='columns'` and as expected i get something like:

```
[
  {"col_name": "value_row_1"},
  {"col_name": "value_row_2"},
...
]
```

For some reason the guy who i want to send the file to, needs a root node such that

```
{
 "root_node": [
    {"col_name": "value_row_1"},
    {"col_name": "value_row_2"},
]
}
```

Unfortunately, I have not been able to get this output with pandas. I did it manualy, creating a dictionary and using the json package, but I'm not sure if this will be usefull for perforance reasons.

Which is the most efficient way to do that? The idea is to store the output in aws S3

Comment: Try `{"root_node": df.to_dict("records")}`, and then dump that to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3], "y": [2,5,6]})
df2 = pd.Series([df.to_dict(orient="records")], index=["data"])
df2.to_json(orient="index", indent=2)
```

The output

```
{
  "data":[
    {"x":1,"y":2},{"x":2,"y":5},{"x":3,"y":6}
  ]
}
```